# Merge two tables into third table with an additional column to bifurcate entries

Tags: mysql

I am creating a database **Dealer** in **mysql**, which has three tables **dealer**, **primary_address** and **billing_address**.

The table **dealer** has four fields :

```
`Dealer_id(primary key)       Dealer_name           email_id           Phone_no

1001                          Dell                  Dell@gmail.com     1234567890 
1002                          HP                    hp@gmail.com   `   2345678901
```

The table **primary_address** has three field :

`dealer_id (primary key)(foreign key)    address_line_1      city 
 1001                                    100 Dell office     New York
 1002                                    200 HP office       London`

The table **billing_address** also has three field (similar to table **primary_address**) :

```
dealer_id (primary key)(foreign key)    address_line_1      city   

1001                                    1001 Dell office    New Jersy
1002                                    2001 HP office      Cambridge
```

And the field dealer_id in both the tables **primary address** and **billing address** is also a foreign key which references to the table **dealer**'s field dealer_id, in order to be related with each other.

Since the fields of both the tables **primary address** and **billing address** are identical.
So instead of creating two tables, I want to merge these two tables into another table lets say **address** with an additional field **address_type** which will let us know the type of address like primary address or billing address.

```
dealer_id (primary key)(foreign key)    address_line_1      city        address_type

1001                                    100 Dell office     New York    Primary
1002                                    200 HP office       London      Primary
1001                                    1001 Dell office    New Jersy   Billing
1002                                    2001 HP office      Cambridge   Billing
```

But then the problem arises if I do this, dealer_id can no longer be **primary key** in the newly created table **address**, because it will have duplicate entries.

Should I create another field in the new table **address** which can play the role of primary key along with **dealer_id** as foreign key?

So, please suggest me solution to this problem, so that I can merge the two tables into one.

Comment: I think that (`dealer_id`, `address_type`) can be a unique key. I would have an auto-incrementing `DealerAddressId` as the primary key.

Comment: I think you should create another column which will be the primary key and current dealer_id will be just foreign key not primary key. It should solve your problem. best of luck..